Diagnosing Bluetooth crash
Over the past several weeks, I've been receiving Bluetooth crash notifications immediately after reboot on my Pixel running GrapheneOS. Graphene recently pushed an update to suppress these notifications, and describes them as "harmless crashes occuring on service shutdown for the Android Bluetooth service".
What's confusing to me is that I've never used Bluetooth on my phone; I always have Bluetooth disabled (under both the quick settings toggle and system settings), and airplane mode enabled. Does this mean that Bluetooth is on by default in the BFU state, similar to how the "Sensors off" toggle doesn't apply while the phone is powered off?
Below is an example of the crash logs I've been getting. Thanks in advance for any thoughts.
type: crash
osVersion: google/bluejay/bluejay:14/AP2A.240705.004/2024070201:user/release-keys
uid: 1002 (u:r:hal_bluetooth_btlinux:s0)
cmdline: /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.bluetooth-service.bcmbtlinux
processUptime: 0s

abortMessage: hardened_malloc: fatal allocator error: double free (quarantine)

signal: 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE)
threadName: binder:811_2

backtrace:
/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164, pc 64a24)
/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (fatal_error+44, pc 4e504)
/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (deallocate_small+1572, pc 4bbc4)
/vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.bluetooth-service.bcmbtlinux (android::hardware::bluetooth::hci::HciFlowControl::~HciFlowControl()+36, pc 1c4e4)
/vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.bluetooth-service.bcmbtlinux (android::hardware::bluetooth::hci::shim::Deinitialize()+104, pc 3fdc8)
/vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.bluetooth-service.bcmbtlinux (android::hardware::bluetooth::aidl::bcmbtlinux::BluetoothHci::signal_handler(int)+116, pc 51594)
[vdso] (pc 88c)
/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__ioctl+4, pc cde84)
/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (ioctl+156, pc 7133c)
/system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+296, pc 50848)
/vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.bluetooth-service.bcmbtlinux (main+2628, pc 65664)
/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+116, pc 5d304)


I don't know the Android Bluetooth service(s) very well but it is not unexpected that the service runs even if you have disabled Bluetooth in settings. If an app tries to access Bluetooth functions who should otherwise respond to the functions, telling the app that Bluetooth is not available at the moment?

Thank you, that makes sense. I hadn't considered that possibility.
